# Disable the Notification Centre on a Mac running Ventura 13.4

Tags: macos, terminal, notifications

I have been using a MacBook Air for two years now. Recently, I was interested in disabling my Notification Centre due to it being unneeded and to help with preventing distractions. I did not see a feature like the intent to disable the Notification Centre via Screen Time after looking. I assume there is a Terminal command which can be ran?

Answer (score 3):

You can’t disable the entire Notification Center, but you can allow/disallow notifications:

> [Change Notifications settings on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-notifications-settings-mh40583/mac)
>
> Allow notifications:
> Turn notifications on or off. When you turn notifications off, the alert style and other notification options are dimmed.

#### [Use Focus instead](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/turn-a-focus-on-or-off-mchl999b7c1a/mac.)

That said, I do **not** recommend turning off notifications.  They are there to alert you to timely/important things.  Instead, I highly suggest your configure and enable a/some Focus schedules.  I have several configured:  Head Down (intensive work), Work (less intensive), and Open.  Some are scheduled while others are manually activated.  It will silence notifications during that focus time.

Comment: Or use Do Not Disturb.