# Can I disable the notifications / widget sidebar?

Tags: macos, notifications

As I edit music I often swipe left in such a way that the notification sidebar comes out from the right side of the screen.  It disrupts my work.  Can I disable this sidebar or mouse gesture?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable the Notification Centre on a Mac running Ventura 13.4](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/461104/disable-the-notification-centre-on-a-mac-running-ventura-13-4)

Comment: @Allan thanks for the link.  It doesn't look like that solution is going to keep the sidebar from coming out with the mouse gesture though

Comment: You have to “click” the date/time to open [Notification center](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/get-notifications-mchl2fb1258f/mac).  How are you moving so that it opens?

Answer (score 1):

In the "More Gestures" tab of *System Settings > Trackpad*, there is an option called "Notification Centre". Simply disable this option for the shortcut to be disabled.

[image]